# Design pattern suggestion/implementation using java 8

Tags: java, algorithm, spring-boot, design-patterns, java-8

I have to process requests in a series of steps.

**For example:** if request 1 comes, then I have to apply step1, step2, step3 and finally step4 which will persist the processed request into the database.

I thought of implementing the **Template design** pattern, as it solves a similar problem.

When I started implementing the design pattern, I suddenly found it hard to implement, because of the logical complexity.

Let me explain the requirement:

**Request -> Controller -> run()**

The **request** will contain `List<objects>`.
Inside **the run** method, a series of operations will be fired.

```
request.parallelStream()
    .map(step1 -> executeStep1.apply(step1))
    .map(step2 -> executeStep2.apply(step2, action))
    .map(step3 -> executeStep3.apply(step3, rules))
    .map(step4 -> executeStep4.apply(step4))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Function<String, List<PersonDto>> executeStep1= person-> {
        return metaData.getMetaDataPerson(person);
    };

    BiFunction<List<PersonDto>, String, TransTemplateDTO> executeStep2= (metaData, action) -> {
        return temlate.createTemplate(metaData, action);
    };
```

Now, as we can see I am passing the first element of `request` as an input to step1(), and then processing it and further passing the output as an input to subsequent steps.

- **Problem 1**:
  Till this point, there was no problem. But suddenly the requirement changed and now I have to add rules logic in the step3 i.e.  `executeStep3.apply(step3)`.

  step3 is taking 2 parameters, one is the output of step2 and second is List rules.
  Step3 should apply all the rules and return the results equal to the rules.
  For ex. If there are 3 rules, then step3 should return a List of 3 objects.
  Let's assume step3 received List of `PersonDto` with 10 items and List of rules of 3 items, then step3 should return 10*3 = 30 records.
  Also for each person rules will vary as per the command.
- **Problem 2**:
  In step 3, I need the request object, so that I can make use of values.
  Something like this:
      `.map(step3 -> executeStep3.apply(step3, rules, request))`

What design patterns help out here, and how?

Comment: (I do not see a special relation to *Spring Boot*, the *eighth version of Java* or any *sequence of well-defined steps that defines an abstract solution*: please make obvious in the question or remove those tags.)

Comment: @greybeard - If you can go through the code, then you can notice that I am using parallelStream(), which is a part of Java 8.

Comment: Whether I can or not, current is release 13, and nothing indicates `java.util.Collection.parallelStream()` is going to be deprecated anytime soon. There is a tag for [tag:java-stream].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **dung ta van** has already mentioned, the first thing that comes to the mind is **Chain of Responsibility** pattern. I will reuse the example and change some things there.

```
public class ChainOfResponsibility {

    protected List<RequestProcessor> handlers = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addHandler(RequestProcessor handler) {
        this.handlers.add(handler);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void handle(Request request) {
        handlers
                .stream()
                .reduce(RequestProcessor::andThen)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Functions can't be composed"))
                .apply(request, null);
    }

    public interface RequestProcessor<T, R> extends BiFunction<Request, T, R> {

        default <V> RequestProcessor<T, V> andThen(BiFunction<Request, ? super R, ? extends V> after) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(after);
            return (Request r, T t) -> after.apply(r, apply(r, t));
        }

    }

    public static class PersonExtractor implements RequestProcessor<Void, PersonDto> {
        @Override
        public PersonDto apply(Request request, Void aVoid) {
            return new PersonDto("Nick");
        }
    }

    public static class ValidatePersonHandler implements RequestProcessor<PersonDto, PersonDto> {
        @Override
        public PersonDto apply(Request request, PersonDto personDto) {
            if (personDto.getName() == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("name can't be null");
            }
            return personDto;
        }
    }

    public static class SetPersonIdHandler implements RequestProcessor<PersonDto, List<?>> {

        private final List<Rule> rules;

        public SetPersonIdHandler(List<Rule> rules) {
            this.rules = rules;
        }

        @Override
        public List<?> apply(Request request, PersonDto personDto) {
            personDto.setId(1);
            rules.forEach(rule -> System.out.println("invoke rule " + rule.toString()));
            return Arrays.asList(personDto, personDto, personDto);
        }

    }

    public static class InsertPersonToDBHandler implements RequestProcessor<List<PersonDto>, Object> {

        @Override
        public List<?> apply(Request request, List<PersonDto> persons) {
            persons.forEach(person -> System.out.println("insert person: " + person.getName() + " to db"));
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChainOfResponsibility chain = new ChainOfResponsibility();

        chain.addHandler(new PersonExtractor());
        chain.addHandler(new ValidatePersonHandler());
        chain.addHandler(new SetPersonIdHandler(Arrays.asList(new Rule("1"), new Rule("2"))));
        chain.addHandler(new InsertPersonToDBHandler());

        chain.handle(new Request());
    }
}
```

In short, we introduce **`RequestProcessor`** interface which is a `BiFunction` indeed. We bind the first argument to `Request` and second one is an outcome from the previous function invocation. Moreover, each of the handler can be provisioned with rules as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Chain of Responsibility](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/chain-of-responsibility) design pattern

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class PersonDto {
    protected int id;
    protected String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class ChainOfResponsibility {

    protected List<Handler> handlers = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addHandler(Handler handler) {
        this.handlers.add(handler);
    }

    public void handle(PersonDto person) throws Exception {
        for(Handler handler : handlers)
            handler.handle(person);
    }

    public static interface Handler {

        void handle(PersonDto person) throws Exception;

    }

    public static class ValidatePersonHandler implements Handler {
        @Override
        public void handle(PersonDto person) {
            if(person.getName() == null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("name can't be null");
        }
    }

    public static class SetPersonIdHandler implements Handler {
        @Override
        public void handle(PersonDto person) {
            person.setId(1);
        }
    }

    public static class InsertPersonToDBHandler implements Handler {
        @Override
        public void handle(PersonDto person) {
            // insert to db
            System.out.println("insert person: " + person.getName() + " to db");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ChainOfResponsibility chain = new ChainOfResponsibility();
        chain.addHandler(new ValidatePersonHandler());
        chain.addHandler(new SetPersonIdHandler());
        chain.addHandler(new InsertPersonToDBHandler());
        PersonDto person = new PersonDto();
        person.setName("foo");
        chain.handle(person);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. your answer somewhat closer to my problem but in my case, I am transforming the output of the first handler to a different object. But in your code snippet, you have used the \same object and passed it to all the handlers.

Comment: you can use my answer, and append an ```output``` parameter to ```Handler.handle``` function, example: ```void handle(PersonDto person, Map output)```

Comment: Yes, I can, but after each handler, there will be the new output format.